# Проблема с передвижением объекта С#

Tags: c#, winforms

Здравствуйте! Я только начал разбираться с C#, хочу нарисовать движущийся круг. Написал такие методы:

```
private void draw()
{
    Pen myPen = new Pen(Color.Black);
    g.DrawRectangle(myPen, 10, 10, 50, 50);
    g.DrawEllipse(myPen, (float)xStart, (float)yStart, 5, 5);
}

private void updateCoords(object obj)
{
    if (xStart < 10)
        dx = -dx;
    if (xStart > 60)
        dx = -dx;
    if (yStart < 10)
        dy = -dy;
    if (yStart > 60)
        dy = -dy;
    xStart = xStart + dx;
    yStart = yStart + dy;
    draw();
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int time = 0;
    TimerCallback tc = new TimerCallback(updateCoords);
    System.Threading.Timer timer = new System.Threading.Timer(tc, ++time, 0, 100);
}
```

Когда нажимаю на кнопку, круг начинает перемещаться, но каждый раз, когда он рисуется заново, старые круги не пропадают, т.е. отображается много кругов сразу. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать, чтоб в каждый момент отображался только один круг в текущем положении. Использую Visual Studio 2015.

**Добавлено**

```
Graphics g; // определяется в классе, но снаружи методов
public Form1() // есть у меня такой метод ещё
{
    InitializeComponent();
    g = panel1.CreateGraphics();
}
```

Comment: закрашивать старый круг или весь холст. Что есть `g`?

Comment: Сделайте свой компонент, переопределите метод `OnRender()` или как то так.

Comment: Спасибо! Закрашивание старого круга помогло, то есть этот вариант подходит. Сейчас буду пробовать переопределить метод OnRender().

Comment: Метод в WinForm называется `OnPaint()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пример вот вам класс, но естественно его необходимо переделать под себя.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
public class MyPainter : Control
{
    private int _xStart, _yStart, _dx, _dy;
    private readonly System.Threading.Timer _timer;

    public MyPainter()
    {
        int time = 0;
        _timer = new System.Threading.Timer(UpdateCoords, ++time, 0, 100);
    }

    ~MyPainter()
    {
        _timer?.Dispose();
    }

    public void UpdateCoords(object obj)
    {
        _dx--;
        _dy--;
        if (_xStart < 10)
            _dx = -_dx;
        if (_xStart > 60)
            _dx = -_dx;
        if (_yStart < 10)
            _dy = -_dy;
        if (_yStart > 60)
            _dy = -_dy;
        _xStart = _xStart + _dx;
        _yStart = _yStart + _dy;
        Invalidate();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.White, new Rectangle(0, 0, Size.Width, Size.Height));
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, 10, 10, 50, 50);
        e.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Black, new Rectangle(_xStart, _yStart, 40, 40));
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь я вроде понимаю, что мне делать.